# If I had money / Had I money, I would like to buy a car

Tags: difference, inversion

> If I had money, I would like to buy a car.

> Had I money, I would like to buy a car.

Are they correct and if not, why?

Comment: would you say "have I money" instead of " I have money"? "had I money" doesn't make sense. You may say  "he had my money" though

Comment: @TangHo *Had I money* is fine. It used to be a common way of phrasing conditionals. It's no longer as common, but it's still acceptable. *Have I enough money in a week, I will buy myself a car* is also fine. Additionally, it can be used when asking a question: *Have I enough money to buy a car?*

Comment: Appreciate your help

Answer (score 1):

They are both correct; the second one is not the 'natural' way a native English speaker would say it.

Comment: Thanks for the help